# ¿deseo buscar el interes moratorio de una cuota por mes segun el numero de dias de interes moratorio que tenga?

Tags: php

Ya he intentado esto, lo que realmente necesito para ser mas exacto es poder calcular el interes de una cuota por mes segun su numero de dias es decir si tiene 36 dias de mora, poder coger 30 dias de un mes y calcular el interes con esa tasa, y los 6 restantes calcularlos del siguiente mes, como deberia de hacer este algoritmo, lo he intentado con un for, pero parece que hace un bucle infinito, de ante mano muchas gracias

```
 $totalInteresMoratorio=0;
       $acumuladoDias=0;
       if (isset($_POST['fechaProgramada'])){
           $fechaProgramada = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['fechaProgramada']);
           $year = substr($fechaProgramada,'0', '4');
           $mes = substr($fechaProgramada, '5', '2');
       }
       if (isset($_POST['diasMora'])){
           $diasMora = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['diasMora']);
       }

       $count=1;
       for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

           $sql = "SELECT * FROM `intereses_moratorios` WHERE YEAR(fecha_inicio)='".$year."' AND  MONTH(fecha_inicio)='".$mes."'  ";
           $result = $conn->query($sql);
           if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                   $fechaInicioIM = $row['fecha_inicio'];
                   $fechaFinalIM = $row['fecha_final'];
                   $from = date_create($fechaInicioIM);
                   $to = date_create(date($fechaFinalIM));
                   $diasMesIM  = date_diff($from, $to);

                   $output []= $row;
               }
           }else {
               $output= json_encode('not_mes_interes)');
           }
           $diasCalculo= $diasMora - $diasMesIM->days;
           if ($diasCalculo > 0){
               $count++;
               date($mes, strtotime('+1 month'));
           }else{
               $count=0;
           }
       }
       echo json_encode($output);
       $conn->close();
```